# angularjs ionic framework navigator loading not working and after splashscreen hide

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i am using ionic framework and use navigator loading.

i have installed this plugin

```
  cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

and used this method:

```
 navigator.notification.activityStart("Please wait....", "loading");
 navigator.notification.activityStop();
```

config file :

```
  <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>
```

not working. Didn't come any error and one help after falshscreen hide show loading box

Comment: add one more line inside your config 
`<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
        <param name="id" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />` , I think you missed it

Comment: thank you.@pankajparkar  No, i have included that one. navigator.notification.activityStart("Please wait....", "loading"); working fine phonegap project . i worked and tested. but ionic app navigator.notification.activityStart not working. any help

Comment: try `window.setTimeout(function() { navigator.notification.activityStop(); }, 100);` hope this could work

Comment: @pankajparkar Sorry, not working window.setTimeout(function() { navigator.notification.activityStop(); }, 100); but phonegap project workig well. only ionic project app not working. But navigator.notification.alert(); working in ionic app.only loading not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this ionic angularjs framework loading problem.

Here is the solution:
loading and hide is use inside this controller

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$ionicLoading) {

     /* ionic Loading show */
                        $scope.loadingIndicator = $ionicLoading.show({
                                content: 'Loading Data..',
                                animation: 'fade-in',
                                showBackdrop: true,
                                maxWidth: 600,
                                showDelay: 500
                        });


    /* ionic Loading hide with Timeout */
                        window.setTimeout(function(){
                                $scope.loadingIndicator.hide();
                        },10000);

});
```